# why the ctye<>()widen in vs2015 return 0xffff

Tags: c++

```
std::locale loc("German_germany");
std::locale::global(loc);

std::string s = "nj \xa2 + \x80 1\n";

std::cout << "string:"<<s ;

std::wstring ws = to_wstring(s, std::locale("German_germany"));
```

and the to_wstring is

```
std::wstring to_wstring (const std::string& str,
                     const std::locale& loc = std::locale()){
    std::vector<wchar_t> buf(str.size());
    std::use_facet<std::ctype<wchar_t>>(loc).widen(str.data(),
                                                  str.data()+str.size(),
                                                  buf.data());
return std::wstring(buf.data(),buf.size());
}
```

and when cout s,the output is

> string:nj ￠ + € 1

It is what I want.
but when the program execute the to_wstring,ctype<>().widen() in it, the thing change to wrong. The ￠ is widen to 0xffff.
It's surprise that the widen output of € is right.It change from 0x80(8 bit windows encoding) to 0x20ac(UTF16/USC2 encoding)
Why?

I find this example in book of The C++ Standard Library, 2nd editon, 3rd print.In the original example, the \xa2 is instead of \xe4. That letter can not cout from string s, and also widen to 0xffff.

Comment: and my system is windows 10 pro chinese version, the ide is vs2015 enterprise english version